# Random vector and marginal distributions: integration limits and support related problems

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, marginal-distribution

Assume the random vector $(X,Y)$ has joint probability density function given by
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
kx(x-y) & \text{if}\,\,0 < x < 2\,\,\text{and}\,\,-x < y <x\\\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Determine the following:

(a) The value of the constant $k$

(b) The marginal probability density function of $X$

(c) The marginal probability density function of $Y$

(d) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Justify your answer.

**MY SOLUTION**

(a) Since $f_{X,Y}$ is a joint probability density function, it must satisfy the relation
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = k\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-x}^{x}(x^{2} - xy)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = k\int_{0}^{2}2x^{3}\mathrm{d}x = 1 \Rightarrow k = \frac{1}{8}
\end{align*}

(b) According to the definition of marginal distribution, we get
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = \int_{-x}^{x}\frac{x^{2}-xy}{8}\mathrm{d}y = \frac{x^{3}}{4}
\end{align*}

where $x\in[0,2]$.

(c) Analogously, we have
\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{|y|}^{2}\frac{x^{2} - xy}{8}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{48}(-2|y|^{3} + 3y|y|^{2} - 12y + 16)
\end{align*}

where $y\in[-2,2]$.

(d) No, because $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \neq f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$.

Once again, I am having problem with the integration limits and as well as to the support for $Y$. Could someone check the results for me? Besides helping me out, is there any tip to avoid miscalculating them, [such as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095674/assume-that-x-and-y-have-joint-probability-density-function-f-x-y-calcu)?